# Cleaner way of handling addition of summarizing rows to table?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that is unique by 5 variables, with two dependent variables. My goal is for this dataset to have appended to it additional rows with TOTAL as the value of independent variables, with the values of the dependent variables changing accordingly.

To do this for a single independent variable is not a problem, I would do something along the lines of:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select "TOTAL" as independent_var1,
independent_var2,
...
independent_var5,
sum(dependent_1) as dependent_1,
sum(dependent_2) as dependent_2
from have
group by independent_var1,...,independent_var5;
quit;
```

Followed by appending the original dataset in whatever fashion you choose. However, I want the above, yet x5 (for each independent variable), and then again for each possible combination of TOTAL/nontotal across the 5 independent variables. Not sure just how many datasets that is off the top of my head...but it's a decent amount.

So best strategy I've come up with so far is to use the above with some mildly creative macro code to generate all possible table combinations of total/non-total, but it seems like SAS just might have a better way, maybe tucked away in an esoteric proc step I've never heard of...

--

Attempt to show example, using three independent variables and 1 dependent variable:

```
Ind1|2|3|Dependent1
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 3
0 1 0 5
0 1 1 7
```

Desired output would be:

```
0 0 ALL 4
0 1 ALL 12
0 ALL 0 6
0 ALL 1 10
ALL 0 0 1
ALL 0 1 3
ALL 1 0 5
ALL 1 1 7
0 ALL ALL 16
ALL 0 ALL 4
ALL 1 ALL 12
ALL ALL 0 6
ALL ALL 1 10
ALL ALL ALL 16
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 3
0 1 0 5
0 1 1 7
```

I may have forgotten some combinations, but that should serve to get the point across.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `PROC MEANS` or `PROC TABULATE`, both of which sound to me like they'd do this perfectly fine?  Maybe a small example with a couple of IVs and DVs and twenty or so lines to show the 'have' and 'want' would be helpful.

Comment: Added mini example. I've never used proc tabulate in this fashion; I'll try to look into it and see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROC MEANS should do this for you trivially.  You need to clean up the output in order to get it to perfectly match what you want (missing for INDx = "ALL" in your example) but otherwise it gets the calculations done properly.

```
data have;
input Ind1 Ind2 Ind3 Dependent1;
datalines;
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 3
0 1 0 5
0 1 1 7
;;;;
run;

proc means data=have;
class ind1 ind2 ind3;
var dependent1;
output out=want sum=;
run;
```

Comment: Looks good! I've got a few questions on it, but they're probably complicated enough they're deserving of their own question. Thanks mate